# How to use radio/select fields to search for users of age less/greater than 17, using Ransack gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am using Rails4 and Ransack.

I do not know how to write in form.
I want to use radio button or selectbox in [all / under 17 / over 18]

```
> User.ransack(birthday_gteq: 17.years.ago).result.to_sql
=> "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`birthday` >= '1999-06-02')"

> User.ransack(birthday_lt: 17.years.ago).result.to_sql
=> "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`birthday` < '1999-06-02')"
```

I am not good at english...